# Web Scrape Images and Load Them into Google Cloud Storage

Tags: web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to web scrape all of the images from a web page, load the jpg files into Google Cloud Storage, and then run each image through the Vision API.

Any suggestions on how to do this in a scalable and automated way? Sounds like we could use a cloud function. Any recommendations and sample code to get started would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I would create a Cloud Function that triggers when a new image is uploaded to your Google Cloud Storage bucket and sends this image to the Vision API to analyze it using [this](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries#using_the_client_library).
Also I’ve found [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/google-vision-api-for-image-analysis-with-python-d3a2e45913d4) that can be helpful. Please note that these links will not help you in the web scraping part.

Comment: Thank you! Any ideas on how to setup a pipeline to scrape the images and bring them into GCS in the first place?

Comment: You could try to do it with [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html). Also in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768694/getting-spider-on-scrapy-cloud-to-store-files-on-google-cloud-storage-using-gcsf) post there is an example that could be useful.